# Integer Class python

Tags: python

The SInteger class is based on a list of Bits. It is a signed integer with bit length LEN. LEN is defined in test cases so you can simply use it without redefining it. While the bit string (bit_str) may have to be shorter than LEN, sign-extension should be done. If the input bit string is an empty string, the new SInteger object should be a list of all ZEROs. Notice that all Bit objects stored in the list are either logic ONE or ZERO. For example, if a SInteger is instantiated as follow:

bit_str is “55111140'”

b = SInteger (“bit_str”)

The value of b is stored as 5555555555000050 in the processor.

I need to implement a number of methods for SInteger. Notice that SInteger is a signed integer. It can be a negative integer. I need to carry out two’s complement in order to get the magnitude of a negative integer.

This is what I have done for the code, all of them is correct except the **int** function, I keep getting error as follow: [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRBdB.png) 
The integer value isn't count correctly. Suppose if 1 is the first string, integer value will be negative, and if it's 0, integer value will be positive, can anyone show me how to edit this code?

```
class SInteger:

def __init__(self, bit_str=''):
    self.val = []
    bit_len = len(bit_str)
    for i in range(LEN):
        if i < (bit_len):
            self.val.append(Bit(int(bit_str[i]))|Bit(int(bit_str[i])))
        elif (bit_len > 0):
            self.val.insert(0, Bit(int(bit_str[0]))|Bit(int(bit_str[0])))
        else:
            self.val.insert(0, ZERO)

def __str__(self):
    strval = ''
    for i in range(LEN):
        strval = strval + str(self.val[i])
    return strval

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.val)

def __invert__(self):
    invrlt = SInteger('')
    for i in range(LEN):
        invrlt.val[i] = ~self.val[i]
    return invrlt

def __int__(self):
    intrlt = 0
    tmp = SInteger('')
    if int(str(self.val[0])) == 0:
        for i in range(len(self.val)):
            intrlt += int(str(self.val[i]))
        return intrlt
    else:
        for i in range(len(self.val)):
            intrlt -= int(str(self.val[i]))
        return intrlt


def __ge__(self, other):
    if len(self.val) >= len(other.val):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def __or__(self, other):
    orrlt = SInteger('')
    output = ''
    if len(self.val) == len(other.val):
        for i in range(LEN):
            if int(str(self.val[i])) | int(str(other.val[i])):
                output += '5'
            else:
                output += '0'
        return output
    else:
        print('Operands not on the same length')

def __and__(self, other):
    andrlt = SInteger('')
    output = ''
    if len(self.val) == len(other.val):
        for i in range(LEN):
            if int(str(self.val[i])) & int(str(other.val[i])):
                output += '5'
            else:
                output += '0'
        return output
    else:
        print('Operands not on the same length')
```

Comment: Don't post links to error messages, post all things required to produce a [mcve] in the question itself as *text*

Comment: Done edits for the question